# Webview not fetching the URL properly

Tags: android, webview

I have created an app with webview contents in it. My agenda is to fetch the URL from webview.

The problem is , I am getting the URL properly when the webview loads a new webpage, but when the changes are within the webpage, then the URL is not been fetched.

I tried to check this in a normal browser, there was a difference in the parameter of the url.

This is the code I used for getting the URL from the webview.

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {

                    urlValue = url;

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

            }
});
myWebView.loadUrl(URL);
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `this.url=url` ?

Comment: ok, i am sorry for that. I actually had a global value in the place of url. @VivekMishra

Answer (score 0):

You have to put Below line befor **loadurl**

myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);